# Get the longitude and latitude by providing the locality address in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to get the geolocation by providing the locality address in windows phone app development.??//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First Of all take a text block to save and see Coordinates .
2. Now Name It as txtBlock1 .

Now you can add the following Code in Map Hold event .

The point where you hold the mouse . it will show you the coordinates both longitude and lattitude.

And you can use them as a string or as a location wise any where

mapMain.Hold += (s, e) =>

```
                {
                    Point p = e.GetPosition(this.mapMain);

                    GeoCoordinate geo = new GeoCoordinate();

                    geo = mapMain.ViewportPointToLocation(p);

                    txtBlock1.text = geo.ToString();


                };
```

Hope It helps...       :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Bing Maps Geocode Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966793.aspx)